# To cache or not to cache $(this) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does creating and reusing a reference increase performance appreciably when the selector is `$(this)`?

I create references for my jQuery selectors when I use the same selector multiple times in the same scope.  The following is more efficient

```
    var jSel = $('div.some_class input.some_other_class');
    some_function1(jSel);
    some_function2(jSel);
```

than this

```
    some_function1($('div.some_class input.some_other_class'));
    some_function2($('div.some_class input.some_other_class'));
```

But what if the selector is simply `$(this)` where `this` is a dom element inside a jQuery method.  Should I bother to create a reference to `$(this)` and reuse the reference or can I create multiple `$(this)` selectors and expect similar performance?

Is the following

```
    var jSel = $(this);
    some_function1(jSel);
    some_function2(jSel);
```

significantly faster than the following?

```
    some_function1($(this));
    some_function2($(this));
```

Comment: [Caching $(this) in jQuery](http://jsperf.com/caching-this-in-jquery/4) or [$(this) vs var xxx = $(this)](http://jsperf.com/this-vs-var-xxx-this) ([jsperf.com](http://www.jsperf.com))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the following significantly faster than the following?

**No**. It is microscopically faster; in the realms of just a few microseconds.

Does that stop you assigning the result to a variable and using that? **No**. Using a variable can give more meaning to what `this` is, and can be easier to type. Plus, if you stopped wanting to operate on `$(this)`, and instead wanted `$(this).next()`, you have to change it in one place instead of `n`.

You'll find the jQuery constructor is *highly* optimized for accepting a single DOM element as a parameter. The following is [the exact code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/255460e4836e86b86f48dd5b7d2a2cbf3f996de2/src/core.js#L78-91) that gets executed when you call `$(DOMElement)` ([after the jQuery object has been created](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/255460e4836e86b86f48dd5b7d2a2cbf3f996de2/src/core.js#L4-7), of course):

```
var match, elem, ret, doc;

// Handle $(""), $(null), or $(undefined)
if ( !selector ) {
    return this;
}

// Handle $(DOMElement)
if ( selector.nodeType ) {
     this.context = this[0] = selector;
    this.length = 1;
    return this;
}

// Handle lots of other param types, but we hit the above one, so we've stopped now...
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how many calls you make. It's certainly faster to set a variable equal to something that does work than to keep doing the same work, but the difference will be extremely negligible in your sample. If you're doing this in a loop of 5 million, the difference will be less negligible and setting the variable will be faster as it only does the work once and not 5 million times.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, if you're really writing functions that expect a jQuery object as a parameter (as in your examples), you could just re-write those functions as jQuery methods.  Then you could write:

```
$(this).some_function1().some_function2();
```

It's pretty easy to write jQuery methods, at least simple ones.  The general (again, simple) form is:

```
jQuery.fn.some_function = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    // stuff you want to do
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes, I agree.  But I wanted to keep my example simple since extending jQuery was not the focus of the question.

Comment: OK well in general, making a function call takes more time than not making a function call. Thus, caching the result of `$(this)` will save a small amount of time. Whether that's worth it is up to you. To me, caching `$(this)` is worth it for the clarity it introduces, particularly if you give the value a good name.

Comment: Do you always cache `$(this)`, or just sometimes?

Comment: In a really simple function, usually not.  In a bigger event handler or something like that, however, it helps clarify what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference to the object. Using `$(this)` takes a bit of time (because of jQuery turning it into an array) but this time is irrelevant IMHO. So the first method should be a bit faster, but actually you won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsperf.com/jquery-cache-vs-no-chace

Should give you a basic idea of speed difference. In most of the simple cases it probably wouldn't affect your code execution speed noticeably but where JS is a bottleneck every bit helps + it's always a best choice to make good practices a routine!

Answer (score 0):

A lil benchmark:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-this-selector-performance