# What is the best practice to manipulate DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I am working with jquery to manipulate DOM elements. I was wondering what is the best approach to load elements from DOM. i.e. will it be more appropriate to load all elements from DOM at once and then use the saved elements to do more operations on it?

```
var $txtName,$txtAddress;
function LoadDOM()
{

 $txtName=$('#txtName');
 $txtAddress=$('#txtAddress');

}

function doSomething()
{
  $txtName.val('Name');
  $txtAddress.val('Address');
}
```

Earlier I used to do following

```
function doSomething()
    {
      $('#txtName').val('Name');
      $('#txtAddress').val('Address');
    }
```

Am I doing this right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849692/jquery-object-to-cache-or-not-to-cache , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296231/to-cache-or-not-to-cache-this-in-jquery

Comment: ty.. seems that i wasn't searching the right term 'cache'..